# How to render a formset inside an Accordion in django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, accordion, django-crispy-forms

I'm using crispy forms and I have many formsets which I'm displaying the single page. To make the page more user friendly I decided to use put each formset inside an Accordion.
I used Accordian layout from cripsy/bootstrap3 but it resulted in each form inside formset to be rendered in separate Accordion. I want entire formset to be rendered in one Accordion.

Please let me know how to achieve this?

Inside my FormHelper:

```
            self.layout = Layout(
            AccordionGroup('Profile Key Value Pair',     
                    Div(
                        Row(
                            Div( 'key',         css_class='col-md-6' ),
                            Div( 'value',       css_class='col-md-4' ),
                        ),
                    ),
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crispy forms layout will apply the accordion to each form in formset. Since i want to apply the accordion on formset level. I made the changes in the template file and added the html/css code for wrapping the accordions around the formset.

```
            <div class="panel panel-default"> 
            <div class="panel-heading"> 
            <h4 class="panel-title"> 
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#" href="#{{ formset.prefix }}">{{ formset.legend }}</a> </h4> </div>
            <div id="{{ formset.prefix }}" class="panel-collapse collapse" >
            <div class="panel-body"> 
            {% crispy formset formset.crispy_helper %}  
            </div>          
            </div>
```